# Why can't I pass a pandas TextReaderInstance (created from pd.read_csv with chunking) to another function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator, chunks

I'm trying create an ETL workflow for a big dataset, and it would be easier on my machine if I could do the TL part in chunks. But when I try to do this, it doesn't work as expected:

```
def extract_data():
    csv_name = 'output.csv'
    df_iter = pd.read_csv(csv_name, iterator=True, chunksize=100000)
    return df_iter

def main_flow():
    df_iter = extract_data()
    for df in df_iter:
        print(df.head())

main_flow()
```

I was expecting this to just print out the head of each df, but instead nothing gets printed.

If I keep everything under one function though:

```
def main_flow():
    csv_name = 'output.csv'
    df_iter = pd.read_csv(csv_name, iterator=True, chunksize=100000)
    for df in df_iter:
        print(df.head())

main_flow()
```

It prints out each df's head as expected. So it looks like passing `df_iter` to another function is what's erasing the info. Could someone explain why? Thanks!